# Проверка значений массива при autocomplete

Tags: php

Есть такой обработчик autocomplete:

```
$us = $db->getAll("select * from `service` where `name` like '%$q%' and `department`=?i",$_GET['data']);
    foreach ($us as $row) {
array_push($return, array(
            'label' => $row['name'],
            'value1' => $row['pr1'],
            'value2' => $row['pr2']

        ));
    }
    echo(json_encode($return));
```

В базе у меня в каждой записи есть поля pr1-pr10. Как вернуть значения тех pr, которые не пустые?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array_filter($row)
```

вернет новый массив и удалит все пустые значения - всё что 0, null, false, пустая строка будет удалено.

Кроме того можете написать свою callback функцию для фильтрации. см: [введите сюда описание ссылки](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое)

Answer (score 0):

Псевдокод:

```
если pr1 != пусто:
    вернуть значение
если pr2 != пусто:
    вернуть значение
```

и т.д.